# password less login not working on mac

Tags: macos, ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

I created public and private keys and updated the public keys in the authorised keys file on the server. But when I try to access the server from my Mac I am still getting the prompt to login. When I try to debug, I am getting the below log message.

```
Pradeep:~ pkumar$ ssh -v pradeep@10.21.21.46
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.21.21.46 [10.21.21.46] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/pkumar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.51.1.36:22 as 'pradeep'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:MkMVA3YQfMFzUv3IxILEVdo0VBr1+aHuQP4YTCbZJg4
debug1: Host '10.21.21.46' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/pkumar/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pradeep@10.21.21.46's password:
```

Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
```

This says that either client or server does not support public key authentication. Client is probably ok, unless you modified your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

If you have access to the server configuration, check the server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure there is enabled `PubkeyAuthentication yes`.